# Who came through in the Great Migration (Liaden Universe)?

Tags: liaden

It is very clear that Terrans, Liadens, and Xtrang came through the great migration; along with cats and the tree(s). Are we ever told if Clutch Turtles did? Or Norbears? Or were they already in the new universe when the others showed up?

Comment: I don't think the Terrans came through; I got the impression that they were the native humans to the universe that the humans eventually called Liadens came to. Certainly, the Liadens, Xtrang, and _dramliz_ came through; the impression I get is that Terrans, Norbears, and the Clutch Turtles were native to the new universe.